# How does the determinant of a matrix change when its elements are multiplied by different constants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let's say we have a $10 \times 10$ matrix. I am wondering how the determinant of the matrix changes when for all $1 \leq i,j \leq 10$ the $i$-th row's $j$-th element is multiplied by $\frac{i}{j}$.

I tried looking at how each permutation in the definition of a matrix changes, but I felt like I was  overcomplicating it. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried modelling this as multiplication on the left by some diagonal matrix $D$ and on the right by $D^{-1}$? What do you know about determinants and similar matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment gave me an idea to construct a diagonal matrix D with the diagonal including the real numbers $\frac{1}{j}$. $$D_{10\times 10} = \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc} 1 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \frac{1}{10} \end{array}} \right]$$ Now if the input 10x10 matrix is the following: $$A_{10\times 10} = \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc} x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,3} &\cdots & x_{1,10}\\ x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} & \cdots & x_{2,10}\\ x_{3,1} & x_{3,2} & x_{3,3} & \cdots & x_{3,10}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ x_{10,1} & x_{10,2} & x_{10,3} & \cdots & x_{10,10} \end{array}} \right]$$ then we can get the desired output by first multiplying each row by its row number (row 2 of matrix A multiplied by 2, row 3 of matrix A multiplied by 3, ..., row 10 of matrix A multiplied by 10). Multiplying a row by $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ will change detA to $\lambda$detA, which, in this case, will change $\det A$ to $10! \det A$. We also know that det(A$\cdot$D) is equivalent to detA$\cdot$detD. Since D is a diagonal matrix, the determinant is just the product of the elements in its diagonal ($\frac{1}{10!}$). Putting all these together, the final determinant comes out to $$10!\cdot \det(A\cdot D) = 10!\cdot \det(A)\cdot \det(D) = 10!\cdot \frac{1}{10!}\cdot \det(A) = \det(A)$$So the determinant doesn't change in this particular problem.

Comment: Please use `\det` instead.